# How to prove $f(M_1 \cap M_2) \subseteq f(M_1) \cap f(M_2)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I am familiar with what $M_1 \cap M_2$ means (and related), but how do I prove something like $$f(M_1 \cap M_2) \subseteq f(M_1) \cap f(M_2)$$

If this relation doesn't hold, I have to come up with a counter example to disprove, but in theory, imagining that would be true, how could I prove (or disprove) this?

I seem to not get my head around that, and I'd appreciate any hint on how I could get a logic chain from the left-hand to the right-hand side.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the real task? This is trivial.

Comment: This is a homework, so real, and I lag prove skills it seems, so I am looking for advice on how to approach to the proof.

Comment: @ChristianParpart could you accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$M_1\cap M_2\subseteq M_i$ $\,(i=1,2)$. Hence $\;f(M_1\cap M_2)\subseteq f(M_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

f(M1∩M2)⊆f(M1)∩f(M2)

Pick y in f(M1∩M2) then there exists an x in M1∩M2 s.t. f(x)=y. But then x is in M1∩M2. What can you conclude about x and subsequently f(x)?

Answer (score 1):

Use $A \subseteq B \implies f(A) \subseteq f(B).$